# Android-Listview items change when scrolling

Tags: android, listview, scroll

as the title says my items keep switching rows, when I scroll through the ListView.
I already read here about the same issue but I cannot figure out what I've done wrong.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View row = convertView;
    RecordHolder holder = null;
    Object o = getItem(position);

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chatmessageitem,null);
        holder = new RecordHolder();
        holder.txtMessage = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txttextmessage);
        holder.messageBubble = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.chatbubble);

        if(o instanceof MessageObject){
            MessageObject m = (MessageObject) o;
            if(m.getEmpfänger() != ((GlobalClass) context).myChatID){
                holder.ID = m.getEmpfänger();
            }else{
                holder.ID =((GlobalClass) context).myChatID;
            }

            holder.message =(m.getMessage());
        }
        row.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (RecordHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    if(o instanceof MessageObject){
        MessageObject msg = (MessageObject)o;
        holder.txtMessage.setText(msg.getMessage());

        if(holder.ID != ((GlobalClass) context).myChatID){
            holder.messageBubble.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.bubbleone));
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            holder.txtMessage.setText(holder.message);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            holder.messageBubble.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }else{
            holder.messageBubble.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.bubbletwo));
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            holder.txtMessage.setText(holder.message);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            holder.messageBubble.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }
    }
    return row;
}

static class RecordHolder {
    String message;
    int ID;
    TextView txtMessage;
    ImageView messageBubble;
}
```

thx for any answeres in advance. Regards.

Comment: why would o not be a MessageObject ? and in this case, why don't you display anything (which actually means not changing the potentially existing convertView)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `holder.ID` based on the current `MessageObject` when the view is created, rather than for each `MessageObject` as the view is recycled.  The content is then set based on that initial (likely erroneous) ID but using the current `MessageObject`.

Move this logic:

```
    if(o instanceof MessageObject){
        MessageObject m = (MessageObject) o;
        if(m.getEmpfänger() != ((GlobalClass) context).myChatID){
            holder.ID = m.getEmpfänger();
        }else{
            holder.ID =((GlobalClass) context).myChatID;
        }

        holder.message =(m.getMessage());
    }
```

to after the `if (row == null) {...} else {...}` block.  (Or incorporate it into the following `if(o instanceof MessageObject){...` block for cleaner code.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these methods to your adapter class:

```
 @Override
  public int getViewTypeCount() {
   return getCount();
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemViewType(int position) {
   return position;
  }
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this code"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: I agree. Thanks for the feedback.